# Simplifying pattern match

Tags: f#

I have these types

```ml
type IntervalWithBreak = { Start: DateTime; End: DateTime }
type IntervalWithoutBreak = { Start: DateTime; End: DateTime; Break: TimeSpan }

type WorkTime =
  | Workshop of IntervalWithBreak
  | Mounting of IntervalWithBreak
  | Ill of IntervalWithoutBreak
 
type WorktimeDefinition = {Weekday: DayOfWeek}
```

Now I want to create a function which allows me to find elements matching a condition.
Code completion for `workTime` in the `matches` function however doesn't provide the `Start` or `End` fields until I use this pattern match.

```ml
let matches (worktime:WorkTime) (worktimeDefinition:WorktimeDefinition) =
  match worktime with
  | Workshop w -> w.Start.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday
  | Mounting m -> m.Start.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday
  | Ill i -> i.Start.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday

List.find (matches worktime) definitions
```

Can I have a more generic match so I don't have to check against all union cases but instead match against `IntervalWithoutBreak` and `IntervalWithBreak`?

My type definition is based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259955/90800).

Comment: It seems like you have your `WithBreak` and `WithoutBreak` back-to-front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the argument of the `Workshop` case and the `Mounting` case is of the same type, the first thing you can do is to join them into an or-pattern:

```
let matches (worktime:WorkTime) (worktimeDefinition:WorktimeDefinition) =
  match worktime with
  | Workshop m 
  | Mounting m -> m.Start.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday
  | Ill i -> i.Start.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday
```

This will not work for the `Ill` case, which contains an argument of a different type. But since they are all records, you can deconstruct the record in the pattern matching too:

```
let matches (worktime:WorkTime) (worktimeDefinition:WorktimeDefinition) =
  match worktime with
  | Workshop { Start = start } 
  | Mounting { Start = start }
  | Ill { Start = start } -> start.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday
```

As you now have just one case, you could actually write this using `let`, but I probably would not do this. I think `match` is more readable. But just for the record:

```
let matches (worktime:WorkTime) (worktimeDefinition:WorktimeDefinition) =
  let (Workshop { Start = s } | Mounting { Start = s } | Ill { Start = s }) = worktime
  s.DayOfWeek = worktimeDefinition.Weekday
```

Comment: Thanks, the second snippet works fine but for the third I get this error: `The two sides of this 'or' pattern bind different sets of variables`

Comment: That is odd! I copy pasted this from my F# editor where it works just fine. Are you sure you have exactly the same thing? (including all the `|` and parentheses?)